# How does the stored charge gets decayed when going from forward bias to zero bias?

Tags: diodes, capacitance, semiconductors, pn-junction, solid-state-devices

In a pn junction diode when **forward biased**, excess **electrons and holes** get stored in **p and n** regions respectively.

If we short the diode by connecting p,n terminals with a wire,

- how do these stored charges decay?
- do they discharge through depletion region, or through the external wire?
- is it identical to a capacitor discharging when shorted?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: hey no just trying to clear my rusty knowledge on diodes

Comment: The energy discharges via the highest resistance when shorted

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 do you mean the *least* resistance, which is the external wire here?

Comment: No the wire carries the current but doesn’t dissipate energy. Only resistance does that.

Comment: The fwd biased diode could be modelled as a capacitance Cd with small fwd resistance Rd in parallel to it.

Comment: The charges in the depletion layer recombine since $np$ is greater than $n_{i}^{2}$.